# Finding both the minimum and maximum in a array with each pass in Selection Sort

Tags: java, sorting, selection-sort

I am working on Java based Array sorting techniques and stumbled across an enhancement in `Selection Sort`

The [documented approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) of Selection Sort talks about finding the largest or smallest object in each pass

> The algorithm proceeds by finding the smallest (or largest, depending
>   on sorting order) element in the unsorted sublist, exchanging
>   (swapping) it with the leftmost unsorted element (putting it in sorted
>   order), and moving the sublist boundaries one element to the right.

I am wondering that its possible to find both the largest & smallest object in a single pass by checking both the conditions

```
public static void mySort(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
            //This will make sure smallest element will come first
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                swap(arr, i, j);
            }
            // This will make sure largest element will come last
            if (arr[j] > arr[arr.length - 1 - i]) {
                swap(arr, arr.length - 1 - i, j);
             // This will ensure that if a smaller element existed at the ending position and got swapped , we are making sure that it doesn't get mixed
                if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                    swap(arr, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what we are doing here is we are sorting from both ends.
This will save some time compared to traditional Selection Sort and Can you please provide your feedback on the approach and if anything similar already exists

More details @ [my blog post](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2017/01/08/selection-sort-enhancement-indian-version/)

Comment: See [this paper](http://www.ijaiem.org/Volume2Issue5/IJAIEM-2013-05-31-098.pdf).

Comment: It is usually the number of comparisons which matters and the number of passes is less but the comparison is the same.  Also selection sort is typically used in small sets for it's *simplicity*, for larger collections a sort with a lower time complexity would be used.

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider .. I guess that paper you pointed out talks pretty much the same

Comment: @BoristheSpider Not a very pleasant read...

Comment: @shmosel yes, the English is quite wonderful; but it does present some experimental results for roughly the same code. The journal is "questionable", but I would have thought that a decent journal wouldn't bother with publishing results of an "improved selection sort" - as [Peter points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41531445/2071828) there are plenty of known algorithms with `O(n lg n)` complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually the number of comparisons which matters and the number of passes is less but the comparison is the same.  Also selection sort is typically used in small sets for it's *simplicity*, for larger collections a sort with a lower time complexity would be used.

When would you use an optimised O(N^2) sort when you could use an O(N log N) sort? Only when N is small, and you want something simple to cover that. e.g. when I want to compare *at most two* elements, I use selection sort.

Comment: This. `O((n^2) / 2) === O(n^2)`, the only way to reduce complexity is to reduce the work  as _a function of the number of items_.

Comment: Thanks @peterLawrey ... yupp .. The comparisons are still the same but the complexity is still in the range of O(n2) ..